# The process cannot access the file 'fullpathandfilename' because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net

Yes, it's a frequent topic.
But I've tried most of the suggestions which is given by the posts.
Such as use a 'using' statement, build a looping structure, error handling, separate functions for handling the delete, checking using the path, etc.
But I keep getting the error. Code is below.
I've tried:

- using a using statement.
- wrapping the code in retries.
- using the full path.
- I've tried to output the line it fails on to the Log file, but it comes back with line zero.
- I've tried splitting out into separate functions for delete etc.

```
 Protected Sub ImageButton3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton3.Click
        If 1 = 1 Then
        'impersonateValidUser(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UserID").ToString(), "DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FilePW").ToString()) Then

        Dim fileLoc As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FileLocation").ToString()
        Dim fileLoc2 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FileLocationtemp").ToString()
        Dim fileLoc3 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FileArchiveLocation").ToString()
        'Dim outputfle As StreamWriter
        Dim strline As String = ""
        Dim carrier As String
        Dim order_no As String
        Dim transId As String = ""
        Dim FileToTest As String
        Dim FileToDelete As String


        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & SqlDataSource3.ConnectionString)
        Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT top 10 * FROM [ export view]"

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, cn)

        cmd.CommandTimeout = 999999
        cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
        Try

            cn.Open()
            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
            carrier = ""
            order_no = ""
            If dr.HasRows Then
                transId = GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Text

            End If
            If transId <> "" Then
                Using outputfle = New StreamWriter(fileLoc2 & transId & ".COMPANYm")

                    While (dr.Read())

                        sb = New StringBuilder()



                        For col = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1

                            If Not dr.IsDBNull(col) Then
                                If Not dr.GetName(col) = "order_no" Then
                                    Dim removestr As String = dr.GetValue(col).ToString().Replace("""", " ").Trim
                                    sb.Append(removestr.Replace(",", " ").Trim)
                                    sb.Append(vbTab)
                                End If
                            Else
                                sb.Append(vbTab)
                            End If

                            If dr.GetName(col) = "order_no" Then
                                order_no = dr.GetValue(col).ToString
                            ElseIf dr.GetName(col) = "carrier" Then

                                carrier = dr.GetValue(col).ToString

                            End If
                            'col = col + 1

                        Next
                        outputfle.WriteLine(sb.ToString)



                        Dim updatesql As String = "UPDATE company_shipping_loads SET upload= '1' WHERE (order_no = '" & order_no & "' )"
                        Dim updatecm As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(updatesql, cn)
                        updatecm.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    End While

                    dr.Dispose()
                    outputfle.Close()
                    'it allowed end using here!
                End Using
            End If
            Dim NumberOfRetries As Integer
            Dim DelayOnRetry As Integer
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim index As Integer
            NumberOfRetries = 3
            DelayOnRetry = 1000
            'NumberOfRetries()
            Try
                For index = 1 To NumberOfRetries
                    index = index + 1
                    'for (index As Integer =1; i <= NumberOfRetries; ++i) 
                    FileToTest = fileLoc2 & transId & ".COMPANYm"
                    FileToDelete = fileLoc2 & transId & ".COMPANY"

                    If funcFileExists(FileToTest) = True Then
                        Console.WriteLine(FileToTest & " existed")
                        ' If File.Exists(fileLoc2 & transId & ".COMPANYm") Then
                        'File.Move(fileLoc2 & transId & ".TXT", fileLoc & transId & ".TXT")
                        'File.Move(fileLoc2 & transId & ".COMPANYm", fileLoc & transId & ".txt")
                        'File.Copy(fileLoc2 & transId & ".COMPANYm", "\\firstbitofpath\secondbitofpath\3rdbitofpath\4thbitofpath\" & transId & ".txt")
                        File.Copy(fileLoc2 & transId & ".COMPANYm", fileLoc3 & transId & ".txt")
                        File.Move(fileLoc2 & transId & ".COMPANYm", fileLoc & transId & ".txt")

                        Console.WriteLine("Ready for delete")
                        funcDeleteFile(FileToDelete)
                        Console.WriteLine("File " & FileToDelete & " should now be deleted")
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' You may check error code to filter some exceptions, not every error
                ' can be recovered.
                If (index = NumberOfRetries) Then
                    '// Last one, (re)throw exception and exit
                    Throw
                    Dim strFile1 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFile").ToString() '"C:\Websites\yourfile.txt"
                    Dim fileExists1 As Boolean = File.Exists(strFile1)
                    'strFile.
                    Using sw1 As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile1, FileMode.Append))
                        ' Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.AppendText(strFile))
                        sw1.WriteLine( _
                            IIf(fileExists1, _
                                "We tried " & NumberOfRetries.ToString() & "times, but we could not conduct the file operations. Error msg may follow:" & ex.ToString(), _
                                "Start Error Log for today " & DateTime.Now & vbNewLine & ex.ToString()))
                    End Using
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(DelayOnRetry) 'Sleep(DelayOnRetry)
                End If
            Finally
                'Do Nothing
            End Try

            'end of new bit


            cmd.Connection.Close()
            cn.Close()
            GridView1.DataBind()
            Dim intzero As Integer
            Dim intnumber As Integer
            Dim result As Integer
            intzero = 0
            intnumber = 1
            result = intnumber / intzero
        Catch ex As Exception

            Response.Write(ex.Message)
            Dim strFile As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("LogFile").ToString() '"C:\Websites\yourfile.txt"
            Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(strFile)
            Dim st As New StackTrace(True)
            st = New StackTrace(ex, True)
            'strFile.
            Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.Append))
                ' Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.AppendText(strFile))
                sw.WriteLine( _
                    IIf(fileExists, _
                        "Error Message in  Occured at-- " & DateTime.Now & ex.ToString() & "Line that errored: " & st.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber().ToString(), _
                        "Start Error Log for today " & DateTime.Now & vbNewLine & ex.ToString()))
            End Using
            Try
                'outputfle.Close()

            Catch es As Exception

            End Try

        End Try
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
        Dim message As String = "You are not able to create the  file. please contact system admin"

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "file creation", "<script " & _
        "language=JavaScript>alert('" & message & "');</script>")
    End If

End Sub
```

Functions:

```
Function funcFileExists(ByVal FileToTest As String) As Boolean
    funcFileExists = (Dir(FileToTest) <> "")
End Function

Sub funcDeleteFile(ByVal FileToDelete As String)
    If funcFileExists(FileToDelete) Then 'See above          
        ' First remove readonly attribute, if set
        SetAttr(FileToDelete, vbNormal)
        ' Then delete the file
        Kill(FileToDelete)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried to write it to the log, like this:
                        "Error Message in  Occured at-- " & DateTime.Now & ex.ToString() & "Line that errored: " & st.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber().ToString(), 

But in the log it just says 'Line Zero':
  at TNT_Transportation.ImageButton3_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)Line that errored: 0

Typcially, it doesn't happen when I debug it. It only happens when the uses use the actual website.